# Recyclerview items unable scroll down.inside tabpane

Tags: android

used tabpane take 120dp height in top.

mainxml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E0E0E0"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context="com.example.suranpc.recy.MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

cardview design xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:padding="16dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"

    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="TextView      :"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
        android:textSize="22dp"

        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.92"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="TextView:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.98"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="20000"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontheader"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="TextView:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstcardtext7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontheader"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


   </LinearLayout>


  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

recycler adapter code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class Readapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Readapter.ProductViewHolder> {


    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Front> productList;

    //getting the context and product list with constructor
 public Readapter(Context mCtx, List<Front> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layoutte,parent,false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Front product = productList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        holder.textView1.setText(product.getbud());
        holder.textView2.setText(product.getbudnum());
        holder.textView3.setText(product.gettosp());
        holder.textView4.setText(product.gettospnum());
        holder.textView5.setText(product.getrem());
        holder.textView6.setText(product.getremnum());
        holder.textView7.setText(product.getremnums());




    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }


    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5,textView6,textView7;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext);
            textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext2);
            textView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext3);
            textView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext4);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext5);
            textView6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext6);
            textView7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstcardtext7);
        }
    }

    }
```

Mainactivity code(add datas):

```
 recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
 productList =new ArrayList<>();
 productList.add(new 
 Front("tested1","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested"));
 productList.add(new 
 Front("tested2","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested"));
 productList.add(new 
 Front("tested3","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested"));
 productList.add(new Front("tested4","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested","tested"));


 Readapter adapter=new Readapter(this,productList);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

only two cards are visible in screen.another two cards not visibled.fixed height datas only showed.(not scrolled). 
 only test1 and test2 datas visible in screen another test3 abd test4 not viewd and scrolled .

appbar xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.suranpc..MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:background="@color/colorTabbg"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorFontwhite"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorFontwhite"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorFontblack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/tbl_pages"/>
    <!-- <tabbed pane" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_pages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

tabpane code in mainactivity
//the tabpane>

```
    ViewPager vp_pages= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vp_pages.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tbl_pages= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_pages);


    final int[]ICONS=new int[]{
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
    };
    tbl_pages.setupWithViewPager(vp_pages);
    tbl_pages.getTabAt(0).setIcon(ICONS[0]);
    tbl_pages.getTabAt(1).setIcon(ICONS[1]);
    tbl_pages.getTabAt(2).setIcon(ICONS[2]);
    tbl_pages.getTabAt(3).setIcon(ICONS[3]);

    //<tabpane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this just Change this in your **`cardview design xml`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"

                >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="TextView      :"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
                    android:textSize="22dp"

                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.91"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="1dp"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.92"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="TextView:"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.98"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="20000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFontheader"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="1dp"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="TextView:"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFontblack"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstcardtext7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorFontheader"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    tools:context="com.example.suranpc.recy.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now only one card display full screen.not scrollable

Comment: print log in your **`getItemCount()`** the size of your list @surankumar

Comment: @surankumar just uninstall your app and again run the project

Comment: two cards display fully.third card headtextview show half.itemcount 3

Comment: @surankumar kumar try to give some **`android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"`** your recyclerview

Comment: Yes i always uninstall my app and run my physical device.

Comment: Card 2 and 3 displayed.first card half displayed.still not scrollable up down cards

Comment: Only not scrolling.datas are added correctly.i cant understand .i used studio navigation drawer template and tabbed pane anything interrupt scrolling.i used blan activity then scrolling working

Comment: used tabpane not scrolling .remove tabppane xml code its scrolling .why

Comment: mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); is it added ?

Answer (score 0):

Display content main xml behalf of tabpane fragment(home page xml).use fragment it works.